# write system call to file desciptor ZERO

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
int main ( )
{
    char C[] = "Hello World";
    write(0,C,sizeof(C));
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I am writing to File descriptor ZERO which I suppose by default is STDIN.. Then why I am I getting output at STDOUT?

```
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$ ./a.out
Hello Worldshadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$
```

Comment: What do you think should happen when you **write** to `stdin`?

Comment: There shouldnt be any output atleast...

Comment: In order for the output to go nowhere, the descriptor referenced by descriptor 0 would have to have the property that input came from a terminal but output was discarded. No such mechanism exists because such a mechanism has no real use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard input is for reading, not writing. What happens when you write to standard input (or read from standard output) is unspecified. Here, both standard input and standard output point to the pseudo-terminal into which the application runs, and the terminal emulator did not take care to make the '0' descriptor "read-only". Hence, the kernel does not prevent writing to standard input, and it goes to the pseudo-terminal just as if it was written to standard output.

For portability, you should not rely on such behaviour.